# Removing a prank

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, download, process, internet-connection

This is a bit of an odd one.

Someone (Probably roommate), somehow, installed something onto my computer that opens a "unsavory" website in my default browser every 10~15 minutes. It's not browser related, as I tried uninstalling chrome and it simply followed me to IE. I've also checked my downloads folder, and I can't find any evidence someone downloaded something either. How can I tell what process is causing this to happen?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Have a look in Task Scheduler

Comment: Just remove the malware, my guess, it wasn't someone but just random malware

Comment: Ran a scan on windows defender and it didn't find anything. Checked the task scheduler as well, and nothing seemed out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think windows defender is quite up to the task. Try comodo internet security
https://www.comodo.com/home/internet-security/free-internet-security.php

It's free and I've been using it for years.  The first scan will take a while but after that you'll be protected.